# Assistance with accessing and storing values

Tags: javascript

So i want to multiple values that i can access later. Here is what i tried:

```
function extraTime(input) {
        var dayAndMonth = {
            Oct: 'October',
            Jul: 'July',
            Aug: 'August',
            Jun: 'July',
            Apr: 'April',
            Feb: 'February',
            Mar: 'March',
            Jan: 'January',
            Thu: 'Thursday,',
            Sat: 'Saturday,',
            Wed: 'Wednesday,',
        };
        return dayAndMonth.input
    }
```

My input, for instance, will be `'Wed'`. I want to then return `'Wednesday'` in response. I have seen something like this done before but not sure if i'm doing it right. I thought it was called a map.

Comment: A Map: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use bracket notation to access your object, e.g.

```
dayAndMonth['Wed']
```

So your complete function might look like this:

```js
function extraTime(input) {
    var dayAndMonth = {
        Oct: 'October',
        Jul: 'July',
        Aug: 'August',
        Jun: 'July',
        Apr: 'April',
        Feb: 'February',
        Mar: 'March',
        Jan: 'January',
        Thu: 'Thursday,',
        Sat: 'Saturday,',
        Wed: 'Wednesday,',
    };

    return dayAndMonth[input];
}

console.log(extraTime('Mar'));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use bracket `[]` notation for this:

```
return dayAndMonth[input];
```